# failing to read 16bit rgb images as numpy arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I am trying to load  own image dataset from a folderwith two sub directories where all the images are 16bit png in RGB scale and the dimension of the images are (64*64). I am converting them to gray scale and forced the numpy array to have data type as uint16. It is returning me a list of images as (64*64) numpy arrays.

```
path="D:/PROJECT ___ CU/Images for 3D/imagedatanew/Training2/"

imageset=[]
image_labels=[]

for directory in os.listdir(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path+directory):
        print(path+directory+"/"+file)
        img=Image.open(path+directory+"/"+file)
        featurevector=numpy.array(img.convert("L"),dtype='uint16')
        imageset.append(featurevector)
        image_labels.append(directory)
```

But when I am trying to convert this list of 2D arrays into a 3D array, I cant do that.

```
im=numpy.array(imageset)
im.shape
>>> im.shape
>>> (207,) ##there are 207 images in total
```

I want the the array as (207,64,64)
and also when I run the im array, it returns me dtype as "object", which I cant understand

Comment: It could be because you are creating a numpy array out of objects, not numpy arrays. Have you tried seeing the dtype of each element before trying to make an array out of them? if they dont all match numpy will make them objects too.

Comment: Verify that all the images are actually the same shape.  Either print `featurevector.shape` before appending it to `imageset`, or check `[a.shape for a in im]`.